# How to remove jQuery from render blocking resources?

Tags: jquery

Is there any possibility to remove jquery.js and jquery-migrate.min.js scripts from render blocking resources? I see this error only on mobile, not on desktop. Scores in Google Page Speed Insights are hight, I know that is unnecessary but if there is any way I want to try...

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmanufakturamocy.pl%2F&tab=mobile

Comment: I'd keep in mind that the way your site is set up, you need jQuery to be loaded before your sliders etc will run. You should optimise for realworld performance, rather than blindly following generic tests

Comment: Slider is on both views - mobile and desktop, but on desktop this erorr isn't show up. Why?

Comment: Who knows, that's something Google set up not me, and not WordPress. I can only surmise that additional or different rules/tests are applied on mobile. Eitherway they won't be testing if the slider is active, these just test the HTML output, they don't run the page

Comment: Ok. Do you think is there any more to do for optimize this site?

Comment: @Damian see this tool: https://github.com/Remzi1993/wp-jquery-manager